# What's the name of this element?

Tags: design-patterns, header, page-layout

[image]

Consider the part in black right above the navigation header. I always knew it as "supra-header," but every time I mention it, nobody seems to know what I'm talking about, so I guess there's a more appropriate name for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, it depends on how it's used.

I've seen this sort of thing used as a **site notice**, ie when you have something temporary that's really important (usually sales). The folks on the graphics design SE [suggest](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/159804/what-is-the-name-for-the-bar-on-a-site-appearing-above-or-below-the-navigation-b) **Notification banner**, **Notification bar**, **Message bar** or **Alert message**.

When using it for navigation, calling it a **two-tier navbar** or **two-level navbar** probably gets the gist across. I see this sort of name referenced in articles like [these](https://uxmovement.com/navigation/the-fastest-navigation-layout-for-a-three-level-menu/), as well as in some stackoverflow questions (though the two-level variant more often than not is referring to "dropdowns containing dropdowns" - that is, a traditional desktop menu).

Also not to be underestimated is the communication method of saying "that top bit" while frantically circling with your cursor over the component.

> I always knew it as "supra-header,"

I only can find car parts for that term, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, "supra header" (or super header) is a made-up term, part Latin/Spanish, part English. In Italy, it's known as "sovraheader" (same case). This is a consequence of using already known pattern elements in English and mixing them with our own languages (mine is Spanish, although "supra" is Latin). Now I understand why nobody gets it!

Comment: I've always thought that it's original name is "announcement bar", but upon googling it I realized that this definition has came from Shopify...

Answer (score 1):

Having a "navigation header" everything above is the "top bar".

In Adobe's graphic applications, there is a top bar on the document window and it is a headache when you lose it because you don't know where to look for it again. It is called "Control Panel".

[image]